# rails puma nginx 111: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, droplet

/shared/tmp/sockets/autostudy-puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.188.181.170, server: www.autostudy.cz

how to fix this error?

## nginx.conf

https://gist.github.com/iLucker93/23491671f7ef7b3eed063b87b7312992

## puma.error.log

- Listening on unix:///home/deploy/autostudy.cz/shared/tmp/sockets/autostudy-puma.sock
- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
  === puma shutdown: 2018-03-26 10:22:56 -0400 ===
- Goodbye!

Answer (score 0):

Try listening on:
`unix:/home/deploy/autostudy.cz/shared/tmp/sockets/autostudy-puma.sock`